# In Postgres 12, how do I set a default schema when logging in using psql?

Tags: postgresql, schema, windows, psql, command-line

I'm logging in to my Postgres 12 (running on Windows 10) db using an alias, which resolves to

```
PGPASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD psql -U${DB_USER} $DB_NAME
```

I would like to find a way to tell Postgres which schema to use by default when logging in, either on the command line or another way.  I tried setting the "search_path" ...

```
> login_to_my_db
psql (12.11)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

my_db_name=> show search_path;
   search_path
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)


my_db_name=> set search_path = 'my_schema';
SET
my_db_name=> show search_path;
 search_path
-------------
 my_schema
(1 row)
```

But as soon as I log out and log back in, the search path setting is gone

```
my_db_name=> \q
> login_to_my_db
psql (12.11)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

my_db_name=> show search_path;
   search_path
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)
```

How can I preserve it or at least tell psql what schema to use when logging in?

Comment: Just change the user `alter user ... set search_path = ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To formalize the answer given in comments, I logged in as the "postgres" (admin) user and ran

```
ALTER USER myuser SET SEARCH_PATH = 'my_schema';
```